# NETLOGO: Drawing Rectangles and Shapes with Patches

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a code that draws squares and rectangle using patches. The variables used are x and y for coordinates of the upper left corner of the shape, l and w for length and width, and c for color.
I used this, and it creates a rectangle where 1,1 is the upper left corner, and it has a length of 5 and width 4.

```
to rectanglebase [x y w l c]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= w and pxcor >= x and pycor <= y and pycor >= (- l + 2)]
  [set pcolor c]
end
to therectangle
  rectanglebase 1 1 4 5 red
end
```

If I want to make x and y be other values, what do i have to fix? every time I put in another value, the output is not what I want. What kind of modifications does my code need so that the drawn rectangle patch will be at the x and y coordinates i put into therectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Two possible fixes : "pxcor <= w" and "pycor >= (- l + 2)"

From the conditional, the pxcor "x coordinates" seem to be between your "x" x-coordinate and "w" x-coordinate, meaning pxcor is selecting from your "x" and your width ("w"). This is the same with the pycor. With some rewriting, the bound becomes more clear.

Rewritten Conditional (where l is length and w is width):

```
ask patches with
  [ w >= pxcor and pxcor >= x
    and
    y >= pycor and pycor >= (- l + 2) ] [ set pcolor c ]
```

Possible Modification (* : modification):

```
ask patches with
  [ * w + x >= pxcor and pxcor >= x
    and
    y >= pycor and pycor >= *(y - l) ] [ set pcolor c ]
```